# Rails app breaks intermittently due to Postgres explain statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql

Rails 3.2.12 app with an external PG DB which has a customers table.  I have a local PG DB that has a "geocodes" table.  The external customer table may or may not have latitude & lingitude for any given customer, so I use the local geocodes table to provisionally populate a lat & long if the customer table doesn't have any lat/long.

So, in rails speak, my customers table "has_one" geocode.

What is happening is I am getting PG Explain errors intermittently when I am selecting customers, and then trying to determine their lat & long:

`` PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "geocodes" does not exist
~                              |: EXPLAIN SELECT  "geocodes".* FROM "geocodes"     WHERE "geocodes"."customer_id" = 1417 LIMIT 1
~                              |Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 586ms
~                              |

~                              |ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "geocodes" does not exist
~                              |: EXPLAIN SELECT  "geocodes".* FROM "geocodes"  WHERE "geocodes"."customer_id" = 1417 LIMIT 1):
~                              |  app/controllers/maps_controller.rb:6:in `all' ``

These errors are triggered by PG EXPLAIN statements which seem to vary in semi-direct proportion to the LIMIT I set.  If the LIMIT of customers is 100, I never get the EXPLAIN triggered, and hence no error.  If I set it at 200, I get errors about 50% of the time.  A LIMIT of 500 has no chance of working that I have seen.

When I set a LIMIT of 200, I have about a 50% chance of the apps page working (it's a google map showing customer locations).  There *seems* to be a correlation between how quickly I refresh the page & whether it will work.  eg: If I quickly refresh the page after a failure, it seems like it works a high % of the time.  If I view the page after an interval of anything greater than several seconds, it seems to fail.

Any ideas on how to cure this?

It's my own general belief that the external PG DB does not know about the local geocodes table, and the EXPLAIN is being triggered on that external DB, and so it blows up.

I don't know enough about PG's inner workings to really figure out how to stop these EXPLAIN statements from happening.

Comment: Rails will automatically run `EXPLAIN` on long-running queries in development mode.  I'm not sure why that's causing an error, though; it looks like the table doesn't exist, but that should also cause an error on any usage, regardless of how long it takes to run.  Are you running this against a DB that hasn't been migrated?  See [the Riding Rails documentation](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/) on configuring explain.  It should only be on in development mode, and it should still execute the query.

Comment: you could turn off explain - in `config/environments/development.rb` change the `config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds`, set it to nil

Comment: Excellent!  Setting the explain threshold to nil did it!

Comment: And Yes the DB was migrated.  I think it is b/c they were on different machines, and the non-local DB just ran these EXPLAIN stmts on a non-existent table, and the whole thing would blow up.  I didn't know that PG would run explain stmts on long running queries.  And the mystery of When it runs these statements remains, I suppose.

Comment: @user2188073 - PG doesn't. Your Rails app does.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking an answer that isn't so roundabout, note that one can also set `config.active_record.silence_auto_explain` in the appropriate environment.